# pandas get the max 3 score rows for each category

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by, greatest-n-per-group

I get a list as follows:

```
cat score name
a   80  fa
c   88  lu
b   36  li
b   96  liu
d   99  zc
b   76  mi
d   89  lu
a   50  fa
d   69  zhang
b   36  huang
d   59  guan
b   96  ka
b   86  chao
c   98  le
a   50  mi
a   90  zc
c   83  chao
b   66  guan
```

How to use pandas can get the max 3 score rows for each cat?  show all the three rows

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) with [`nlargest`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.SeriesGroupBy.nlargest.html):

```
print (df.groupby('cat')['score'].nlargest(3))
cat    
a    15    90
     0     80
     7     50
b    3     96
     11    96
     12    86
c    13    98
     1     88
     16    83
d    4     99
     6     89
     8     69
Name: score, dtype: int64
```

If need [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) and remove `level=1` of `Multiindex`:

```
df1 = df.groupby('cat')['score']
        .nlargest(3)
        .reset_index(level=1, drop=True)
        .reset_index()

print (df1)
   cat  score
0    a     90
1    a     80
2    a     50
3    b     96
4    b     96
5    b     86
6    c     98
7    c     88
8    c     83
9    d     99
10   d     89
11   d     69
```

EDIT by comment:

Before `groupby` [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) from column `name`:

```
df1 = df.set_index('name').groupby('cat')['score'].nlargest(3).reset_index()
print (df1)
   cat   name  score
0    a     zc     90
1    a     fa     80
2    a     fa     50
3    b    liu     96
4    b     ka     96
5    b   chao     86
6    c     le     98
7    c     lu     88
8    c   chao     83
9    d     zc     99
10   d     lu     89
11   d  zhang     69
```

EDIT1 by comment1:

If `score` column is set to `0`, try add parameter `name='score'` to `reset_index()`

```
df1 = df.set_index('name').groupby('cat')['score'].nlargest(3).reset_index(name='score')
```

Another solution is `rename`:

```
df1 = df.set_index('name')
        .groupby('cat')['score']
        .nlargest(3)
        .reset_index()
        .rename(columns={'0':'score'})
```

If have multiple columns add them to `set_index`:

```
df1 = df.set_index(['name', 'name1', 'name2'])
        .groupby('cat')['score']
        .nlargest(3)
        .reset_index(name='score')
```

Comment: thank you ,i try it ,but the "score"  show  "0" ,  what did it happen?

Comment: instead numbers there are `0`? What is `df.info()` ?

Comment: like this :   cat  0
0    a     90
1    a     80
2    a     50
3    b     96
4    b     96
5    b     86
6    c     98
7    c     88
8    c     83
9    d     99
10   d     89
11   d     69

Comment: thank you ,i have saw it .  i hava two questions : 1 ： why did the result  replace the word “score”  to "0" ,just the word  has changed. not the data below.  2： if i has so many columns,  how did show it all convenient

Comment: Please see edit1, maybe `score` is `0` because you have lower version of pandas.